# What's stored on a thread's stack?

Tags: linux, stack

I'm learning about threads right now and am confused as to what's stored in a thread's stack.  Is it just its own set of local variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That, and return addresses and frame pointers - but this is no different then a non threaded application.